# How to click a button that is part of a menu item with TestStack White automation

Tags: c#, ui-automation, white-framework

I'm learning to use White by TestStack to automate a Windows application. I am trying to automate creating a new project by going through the application's menu item with the path "File>>Project>>New..." So far I've gotten the automation to do "File>>Project" but it errors out on "New..." because it "Failed to get (ControlType=button or ControlType=check box),AutomationId=New...". The tool I'm using to pull the UI information from is Visual UI Automation Verify.

Source Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        string prog = @"C:\Program Files\CounterTack\Responder\Responder.exe";
        TestStack.White.Application app = TestStack.White.Application.Launch(prog);
        Window window = app.GetWindow(SearchCriteria.ByText("Responder® Professional Edition for Windows"), 
            TestStack.White.Factory.InitializeOption.WithCache);
        window.WaitWhileBusy();


       var cFile = window.MenuBar;
       string[] path = { "File", "Project"};        
       cFile.MenuItem(path).Click();

       Button cNew = window.Get<Button>("New...");
       cNew.Click(); 
    }
```

I have tried doing:

```
var cFile = window.MenuBar;
       string[] path = { "File", "Project", "New..."};        
       cFile.MenuItem(path).Click();
```

But since "New..." isn't a menu item, I get an error for that too. Any ideas/ resources on how to click the "New.." button?

Comment: Could you post a screen shot of the new buttons properties from inspect?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if u still have problem probably not but u could have tried this:

```
var menu = window.MenuBar.MenuItem("File", "Click Me");
        menu.Click();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to find menubar manually.

```
var menuBar = window.Get<MenuBar>(SearchCriteria.ByText("MENUBAR_SEARCH_CRITERIA"));
```